# how to insert maximum 15 cards on add button

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core-mvc

This code is not working i have made a button adddmore in that  the cards are appending when i click on it but i want to specific if i click on button more than 15 times the button should disable

```
function AddMore() {
        var counter = 0;

        var clonehtml = $(".manage").html();
        if(counter < 5) {
            counter++;  
            $("#manageview").append(clonehtml);
            
        }
        else {
           // $("#Addmore").attr('disabled',false);
        }

    }
```

Comment: move the counter outside the function

Comment: Just like what @mplungjan said, you need to define `counter` as a global variable which is  defined out of the function, what you write now is defining a partial variable. I'm afraid you only need to move the line `var counter = 0;` up 2 lines.

Answer (score 0):

You could move the counter outside the function but this is likely what you wanted

```
function AddMore() {
  const counter = $("#manageview").find(".manage").length;
  if (counter >= 5) return; // leave
  var clonehtml = $(".manage").html();
  $("#manageview").append(clonehtml);
}
```

You can do this too - I use eq(0) to only get one .manage element

```
const $manageView = $("#manageview")
function AddMore() {
  const counter = $manageView.find(".manage").length;
  $("#Addmore").attr('disabled',counter >= 5);
  if (counter >= 5) return; // leave
  var clone = $(".manage").eq(0).clone(true);
  $manageView.append(clone);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function AddMore() {
    var numitem = $(".galleryviewcard").length;
    var counter = 0;
    if (numitem < 16) {
        counter++;
        var clonehtml = $(".manage").html();
        $("#manageview").append(clonehtml);
    } else {
        $("#Addmore").prop('disabled', true);
    }

}
```

// This is just a sample script. Paste your real code (javascript or HTML) here.

```
if ('this_is' == /an_example/) {
    of_beautifier();
} else {
    var a = b ? (c % d) : e[f];
}
```